# Access all Data from databound RadGrid?

Tags: c#, asp.net, radgrid

Is there are way to access all of the data from a databound RadGrid?

I can acess the data that is currently showing on the RadGrid, but is there anyway to access the data that is bound to the control but not shown?

Say I have 125 records, but only 25 are shown on the page, how do I access the other 100?

Comment: Are you trying to get the data after the aspx page has been generated?  If so, it doesn't exist at that point.  If you want it before the page has been generated, don't you already have that in your hand?

Comment: I'm trying to get the data after the page has been generated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution to the question that works, but I am not sure if there is a better solution than this

```
for (int i = 0; i < Ragrid.Pagecount; i ++)
{
    RadGrid.CurrentPageIndex = i;
    RadGrid.Rebind;

    foreach(GridDataItem item in RadGrid.Items)
    {
         do stuff
    }
}
```